# Using a repeater in C# from VB.net example

Tags: vb.net, repeater

I use repeaters in vb.net all the time and have no problems with them, however i'm working on some c# and can't work out the conversion (and an online conversion jobby didn't seem to work)

I have my repeater set out like:

```
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="span12 grey-box">
                            <div class="hero-block3">
                                <div class="row show-grid">
                                    <div class="span9">
                                        <div class="hero-content-3">
                                            <h2><asp:Literal ID="ltrName" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h2>
                                            <p><asp:Literal ID="ltrDescription" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <div class="tour-btn">
                                            <small>How Many?<br /></small>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbox" Width="40"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

And heres how i'd populate it normally in vb.net

```
Private Sub rptItems_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptClientList.ItemDataBound
        Dim nRow As DataRowView = Nothing

        Select Case e.Item.ItemType
            Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem

                With e.Item
                    nRow = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
                    With DirectCast(.FindControl("ltrText"), Literal)
                        .Text = nRow("Description")
                    End With

                     With DirectCast(.FindControl("ltrTitle"), Literal)
                        .Text = nRow("Name")
                    End With

                End With

        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why you don't just use DataBinding? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Yeah, I need to do an if statement inside the loop of the binding to basically do if boolean = true, hide specific element

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your `Repeater` aspx to specify the event handler:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems" 
              OnItemDataBound="rptItems_ItemDataBound">
     ...
```

And then the event handler in C# will be

```
protected void rptItems_ItemDataBound(object sender, 
                                      System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView nRow = null;

    switch (e.Item.ItemType)
    {
        case ListItemType.Item:
        case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
            nRow = (DataRowView) e.Item.DataItem;
            ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrText")).Text = nRow["Description"].ToString();
            ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrTitle")).Text = nRow["Name"].ToString();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for that. The only problem seems to be it doesn't like nRow("whatever") - "Error 14 'nRow' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'"

Comment: change the parenthesis () for bracker []